# access token retrieved via javascript SDK seems not valid when passing to php

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I retrieve an access Token via the javascript SDK and pass this to the server via a windows.location:

```
<script src='https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<!-- Load javascript facebook connector -->
<script>
    FB.init({
            appId : '<?=$app_id;?>',
            status : true, // check login status
            cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
            xfbml : true // parse XFBML
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getToken(){
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            var access_token = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            window.location="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>?accessToken="+access_token;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }, {scope:'user_likes,friends_likes'});
}
</script>
```

The PHP code:

```
<?php
  $app_id = 'MY_APP_ID';
  $app_secret = 'MY_APP_SECRET';
  $page_id= 'MY_PAGE_ID';

  if(isset($_GET['accessToken'])){
  // Run fql query
  $fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'
. '/fql?q=SELECT+uid+FROM+page_fan+WHERE+page_id='.$page_id.'+AND+uid+IN+(SELECT+uid2+FROM+friend+WHERE+uid1=me())&'.$_GET['accessToken'];
  echo $fql_query_url;
  $fql_query_result = file_get_contents($fql_query_url);
  $fql_query_obj = json_decode($fql_query_result, true);

  //display results of fql query
  foreach($fql_query_obj as $v1){
    foreach($v1 as $v2){
        $x++;
    }
}
echo "You have ".$x." friends who 'like' us";
```

}

When I echo the $fql_query_url and past the url in the browser, facebook graph api answers

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104
   }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I DO get an access token but it seems not to be valid?

Comment: Try linting the access token at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint and see if it is valid there.

Comment: Also, do NOT pass the access token as a GET parameter; it can be leaked to any third party sites you include content from and can be a huge security hole

Comment: When I lint the access token from the GET parameter it validates, including the correct permissions. But the FQL query does not return the value... When I use the same query with an access token requested via the graph API it IS working.

When the app is working I'll pass the access token via an POST. I think that will be safe enough?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missing `access_token` in the actual request since you just adding the `access_token` to the URL without actually naming that parameter. Add `access_token=` before adding `$_GET['accessToken']` to URL.

It's really great to have your source readable to discover this kind of things:

```
$query = <<<FQL
SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id = {$page_id} AND uid IN (
  SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()
)
FQL;
$fql_query_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=' . rawurlencode($query);
$fql_query_url .= '&access_token=' . rawurlencode($_GET['accessToken']);
```

BTW, it's a really bad maner to pass `access_token` via GET parameters, try to avoid this.

Comment: Thanks, solved the issue! And I will use a POST in the final script.